# Error cargar imagen de fondo en JPanel en un JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, imageicon

Tengo un `JFrame` en el cual quiero ocuparlo entero con un `JPanel` y en el `JPanel` poner una imagen de fondo.

**Código:**

```
public class InicioSesion extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    private Image imagenFondo;
    private URL fondo;

    public InicioSesion() {
        initComponents();

        fondo = this.getClass().getResource("fondo.jpg");
        imagenFondo = new ImageIcon(fondo).getImage();

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.add(PanelFondo);
    }

    public JPanel panelFondo = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.drawImage(imagenFondo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    };
}
```

Imagen del contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba Image imagen=ImageIO.read(new File("fondo.jpg"));

Comment: Me salta el siguiente error: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! Me dice que no pudo leer el archivo. El archivo .jpg está en el mismo directorio que el archivo .java que estoy ejecutando, entonces por eso no puse ruta absoluta.

Comment: Tienes un error en la lectura del archivo. Prueba a editar la foto con algún programa de edición de fotos y guardarlo en otro formato, después lo vuelves a cambiar de formato para volver al formato jpg y pruebas de nuevo.

Comment: Hice un clean and build del proyecto entero y me funcionó con tu código: Image imagen=ImageIO.read(new File("fondo.jpg"));  Ponlo en forma de respuesta y te voto.

Comment: Se me quedan atrás elementos como JLabels y JButtons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mí me gusta usar en mis JPanels el método setBackGround, más que el método paint. Sobre todo cuando son ventanas que no están pensadas para ser redimensionadas, sino que son ventanas pensadas para estarse quietas, como una ventana de logueo.

Para ellas, utilizo objetos Image, en tu ejemplo:

```
Image imagen=ImageIO.read(new File("fondo.jpg"));
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución. ¿Por qué algunos elementos del JPanel los tengo ocultos? ¿Es porque están por detrás de la imagen? ¿Debo usar setOpaque(false);?

Comment: Yo normalmente utilizo el método setBackground y asi me funcoina sin tener que usar el método paint.Así que no tengo demasiada experiencia con el método paint, pero si se te ocurren cosas que podrían solventar tu problema... siempre puedes probarlas antes de preguntar... y luego en la pregunta decirnos qué es lo que has probado, para darnos más pistas a los contertulios.

Comment: ¿Cómo sería el setBackgroud en lugar del paint en tu caso? ¿Cómo quedaria?

Comment: un buen programador investiga sin parar. Y el primer paso siempre en la investigación es la API de java. Así que podrías acudir a la clase JPanel e investigar el método setBackground, ya que si no recuerdo mal, tiene sobre-carga de métodos. Para colores, o para fotos.